# Need help regarding safe area layout

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios11, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I added constraints properly with respect to super view instead of a safe area but still I am facing an issue of grey area on top and bottom of specific screen.it should appear completely on the whole screen at I Phone X. Please follow the screenshot.[image]

Comment: margin  is 0 ???

Comment: @Sh_Khan yeah margin from top and bottom is 0

Comment: please check you top constraints

Comment: you said "On Specific Screen" Please explain this

Answer (score 0):

- Check that you have a launch storyboard and not a fixed launch image
  that does not respect the iphone x screen size
- Check in your top and bottom constraint properties that they are relative to superview and not to margins (by default xcode 9 adds the constraints relative to margin).

[image]

Comment: yeah i have already tried that but it does not work . actually i have a navigation controller and using carbon kit library in my rootviewcontroller, child controller gets added in this root controller . but it does not occupy whole screen.